# python subprocess calls exe files and doesn't work

Tags: python, windows

I'm having a issue with Python and Windows 10.

We have a python that creates a label and then calls another python script who manages the auto-printing using gswin32c.exe and gspring.exe (**Ghostprint + GSPrint**)

The problem is:
If we call the python script (.pyw) using another software (for instance, our ERP) it only generates the label, calls the second script and it doesn't print. If we open py file manually, it generates label and prints...

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you so much

We tried also to separate scripts and call "print_label.pyw" with our ERP. Doesn't print. If we click pyw file it prints...

```
import win32ui
import win32print
import win32api
import win32con
import subprocess

# Routes
GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH = "C:\\XXX\\Ghostscript\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"
GSPRINT_PATH = "C:\\XXX\\GSPRINT\\gsprint.exe"


nombre_archivo = "label.pdf"


nombre_impresora = "Xprinter XP-420B"


ruta_archivo = ".\\" + nombre_archivo


escala = 0.95


comando = [GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH, "-sDEVICE=mswinpr2", "-dBATCH", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dFitPage", "-sOutputFile=%printer%{}".format(nombre_impresora), ruta_archivo]


subprocess.run(comando)


default_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()


hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()


hDC.CreatePrinterDC(default_printer)


hDC.StartDoc("Etiqueta")
hDC.StartPage()


rect = (0, 0, int(hDC.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.PHYSICALWIDTH)), int(hDC.GetDeviceCaps(win32con.PHYSICALHEIGHT)))


image = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
image.LoadFile(ruta_archivo)


hDC.StretchBlt(rect, image, (0, 0, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()), win32con.SRCCOPY)


hDC.EndPage()
hDC.EndDoc()
```

Comment: Hard to know, post the code, how does the ERP call the pyw file? Have you added logging to the pyw to see if any error happens?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's difficult to know why it's not printing given the lack of details.   The ERP calls the second script but doesn't print.  Since you're depending on the ```exe``` files to print, perhaps it isn't finding the file.  Please include more details (particularly the code calls the exe file)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Let me show the code of "print_label.pyw". The script when double click -> prints. When the ERP calls print_label.pyw it does nothing. If i change .pyw to .py for see the console it opens the console but no error. Let me show the code, i'm going to edit